# Interpretation of java hprof histogram

Tags: java, heap-memory, hprof

The hprof, histogram shows the number of object by class.

is this the total number of object that have ever been allocated during  the life of the jvm ?

or is this the number of object where are currently on the heap ?

or is this the number of currently reachable object on the heap ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you're generating dump with "live" (for example `jmap -histo:live PID`) option it's number of reachable objects. In other case it's number of objects currently allocated on heap.

Comment: my hprof was generated on OOM  using hprof=cpu=samples,depth=10 so I am now assuming it number of object currenlty allocated on the heap,  and so reachable ?

Comment: @dmc AFAIK hprof=cpu show cpu usage, not objects histogram. Are you sure you're thinking about objects?

Comment: yes I read this also,  but I do see the histo and all the object and content ect, so maybe its not generated with the args i was thinking,  but it is generated via a OOM. any way. thanks